# Is $\ell_1$ complemented in its double dual $\ell_1^{**}$? (i.e., in $\ell_\infty^*$?)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Quick question, y'all.  Is $\ell_1$ complemented in $\ell_1^{**}=\ell_\infty^*$?

Yes, I searched Google, and also the standard texts.  I can't seem to find an answer, but surely this is known.

Thanks guys.

Comment: $E^\ast$ is always complemented in $E^{\ast\ast\ast}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel Fischer's comment says yes, since $\ell^1=c_0^*$. One can give an explicit projection from $(\ell^\infty)^*$ onto $\ell^1$ by saying $$P\Lambda=(\Lambda e_1,\Lambda e_2,,\dots).$$

Comment: Cool, thanks guys :)